# how do i stop objects from spawning automatic

Tags: lua, coronasdk

ok whenever i try to reload the scene the objects from the previous scene dont stop spawning

here is my code, I want to delete all the objects from screen before moving to another screen

```
local objects = {
    "banana", 
    "grape", 
    "pineapple", 
    "bomb",
    "watermelon", 

}
local function spawnObject()
     objIdx = mRandom(#objects)
    objName = objects[objIdx]
    object = display.newImage( "images/fruit_" .. objName .. "_100.png" )
    object.x = mRandom(screenLeft+30, screenRight-30)
    object.y = screenTop
    object.rotation = mRandom(-15, 15)
    object.id = mRandom(-15,15)
    if objIdx < 4 then
        object.type = "food"
    else
        object.type = "other"
    end
    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert your object (from display.newImage) into the scene view / display group.
Then it will get deleted automatically if you change screen.

Other option is to store all objects in a table, and call removeSelf() on each object in the table when you want to delete them.

Comment: it gives an error. Attempt to index global group (a nil value)

Comment: if you are in a scene, you should have:
function scene:createScene( event )
 local group = self.view

Otherwise it means that your scene group is already deleted in which case you will need to delete your objects manually

Comment: I am sorry, I am a complete noob. here is my code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25693628/how-do-i-restart-the-game?rq=1 . Can you tell how do i restart the game in collision. the thing is i am trying to restart the game but cant seem to. I am new to this, sorry :(